# What can I use in place of Quinoa flour?

Tags: substitutions

What can I use in place of Quinoa flour? The recipe calls for Quinoa flour, but I don't have any.

Comment: In what context or recipe?  See:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-can-we-make-substitution-questions-more-helpful

Answer (score 2):

Rice is initially a seed, but once its husk has been removed, it is considered a grain. After that first stage of processing, you have 'brown rice'. Quinoa is technically a seed, but is only one stage of processing away from brown rice. Brown rice flour is the closest approximation in terms of fiber, caloric content, and binding behavior to quinoa flour that you will find, the major differences being that quinoa flour has approx. 1.5x the fat and 2x the protein found in BRF.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute brown rice flour for quinoa flour (they are both medium flours). 7/8 cup brown rice flour is equal to 1 cup quinoa flour.

Comment: Medium on what scale?

Comment: Just in terms of flour substitutes. There are heavy flours (almond flour), medium flours (brown rice flour and quinoa flour) and light flours (sweet rice flour).

Comment: Okay... but what quality of aspect of the flour makes it light, medium or heavy?